# If Else statement inside the nlapiSearchRecord

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript1.0

Badly need help..
I am trying to add a condition inside my **nlapiSearchRecord** API but the condition is not being followed. Though it is running fine with no errors, the suitelet is looking at the first parameter even if it should follow the else statement.

Please refer at the line: `var arrSearchResults =   nlapiSearchRecord(searchRecordType, null, arrSearchFilters, (searchRecordType = 'transaction') ? arrSearchColumnsTrans : arrSearchColumnsCustomers) || [];`

Even though the searchRecordType is '**customers**', it still follows the **arrSearchColumnsTrans**, not the **arrSearchColumnsCustomers**

---

```
var searchRecordType = request.getParameter ('custpage_rectype'); 
var searchLookupText = request.getParameter ('custpage_lookuptext'); 
var searchLookupField = request.getParameter ('custpage_lookupfield'); 
var searchParameter = request.getParameter ('custpage_searchparam'); 

var arrSearchFilters = [new nlobjSearchFilter(searchLookupField, null, searchParameter, searchLookupText)];
                            
var arrSearchColumnsTrans = [new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid'),
                                  new nlobjSearchColumn('type'),
                                  new nlobjSearchColumn('entity')];

var arrSearchColumnsCustomers = [new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid'),
                                  new nlobjSearchColumn('entityid'),
                                  new nlobjSearchColumn('companyname')];
        
  
var arrSearchResults =  nlapiSearchRecord(searchRecordType, null, arrSearchFilters, 
(searchRecordType = 'transaction') ? arrSearchColumnsTrans : arrSearchColumnsCustomers) || [];
        
var objVal = {};
for (var i = 0, ii = arrSearchResults.length; i < ii; i++) 
{
    var val = arrSearchResults[i];
    objVal[val.getId()] = {};
    objVal[val.getId()].tranid = val.getValue('tranid');
    objVal[val.getId()].internalid = val.getValue('internalid');
    objVal[val.getId()].type = val.getValue('type');
    objVal[val.getId()].entityid = val.getValue('entityid');
    objVal[val.getId()].entity = val.getText('entity');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ternary statement doesn't actually have a conditional:

```
(searchRecordType = 'transaction') ? ...
```

Because you're using `=`, you're just assigning the value of `'transaction'` to `searchRecordType`. If you want to compare the two values instead, you'll want to use `==` or `===`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
All good now..

```
var arrSearchResults = (searchRecordType === 'transaction') ? nlapiSearchRecord(searchRecordType, null, arrSearchFilters, arrSearchColumnsTrans) : (searchRecordType === 'item') ? nlapiSearchRecord(searchRecordType, null, arrSearchFilters, arrSearchColumnsItems) : nlapiSearchRecord(searchRecordType, null, arrSearchFilters, arrSearchColumns) || [];
```